# GROUP BY Clause error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to exclude a term from the `GROUP BY` clause that prevents me from having terms summed up together. The strange thing is that I'm using the term that causes this in a case statement, and the query still wants me to use it in the group by clause or else it will generate an error. How to solve this issue?

To be more specific: The vr.krebel that is used within the case in the `SELECT` clause is forcing me to add it too `GROUP BY`. How to avoid this?

```
SELECT vr.ktonr,
       vr.foretagkod,
       '' AS persign,
       '' AS TYPE,
       NULL,
       1 AS antal,
       SUM(vr.debbel-vr.krebel),
       0,
       vr.kostbar,
       vr.koststallekod,
       vr.projcode,
       vr.redovisnar,
       vr.period,
       'Allocated vouchers' AS artbeskr,
       ko.ktobeskr AS kodescr,
       CASE
           WHEN ((vr.ktonr LIKE '9600'
                  OR vr.ktonr LIKE '3%')
                 AND (vr.krebel>0)) THEN 'Revenues'
           ELSE 'Costs'
       END
FROM vr
INNER JOIN ko ON ko.ktonr=vr.ktonr
AND ko.redovisnar=datepart(YEAR,vr.bokfdat)
AND ko.foretagkod=vr.foretagkod
WHERE vr.foretagkod = 300
  AND vr.intsource = 20
  AND vr.projcode = 50040
  AND (vr.bokfdat BETWEEN CAST('2012-12-01' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('2012-12-31' AS DATETIME))
GROUP BY vr.ktonr,
         vr.foretagkod,
         vr.kostbar,
         vr.koststallekod,
         vr.projcode,
         vr.redovisnar,
         vr.period,
         ko.ktobeskr,
         vr.krebel
```

To be more specific: The vr.krebel that is used within the case in the `SELECT` clause is forcing me to add it too `GROUP BY`, how to avoid this?

Comment: you need to use `AND SUM(vr.krebel) > 0` or another aggregate function in your `CASE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different options here. But I think that the better one for your query would be to add your `CASE` in the `GROUP BY`.

```
select  vr.ktonr, 
        vr.foretagkod,
        '' as persign, 
        '' as Type,
        NULL, 
        1 as antal, 
        SUM(vr.debbel-vr.krebel),
        0, 
        vr.kostbar, 
        vr.koststallekod, 
        vr.projcode,
        vr.redovisnar, 
        vr.period,  
        'Allocated vouchers' as artbeskr, 
        ko.ktobeskr as kodescr,
        case when ((vr.ktonr like '9600' or vr.ktonr like '3%')
                     AND (vr.krebel>0)) then 'Revenues' else 'Costs' end
from vr
inner join ko 
    on ko.ktonr=vr.ktonr 
    AND ko.redovisnar=datepart(year,vr.bokfdat) 
    AND ko.foretagkod=vr.foretagkod
where vr.foretagkod = 300 
AND vr.intsource = 20 
AND vr.projcode = 50040 
AND (vr.bokfdat between CAST('2012-12-01' AS DATETIME) 
                AND CAST('2012-12-31' AS DATETIME))
group by vr.ktonr, 
         vr.foretagkod, 
         vr.kostbar, 
         vr.koststallekod, 
         vr.projcode, 
         vr.redovisnar, 
         vr.period, 
         ko.ktobeskr, 
         case when ((vr.ktonr like '9600' or vr.ktonr like '3%')
                     AND (vr.krebel>0)) then 'Revenues' else 'Costs' end
```